# jqGrid - how to set grid to NOT load any data initially?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, load

How can you create a grid but not load any data?

If I omit the `url` option then the `loadError` callback is triggered.

Currently we set `url:NoData.json` where NoData.json is a static file with no rows in it.

Issue is in our `loadComplete` callback we'd like to dipslay a message if the grid contains no data - except we don't want to display this message on the initial load.  Currently we handles this as follows:

```
//jqGrid load complete handler
function loadComp(grid) {
    if (grid.getGridParam("url") != "NoData.json" && grid.getGridParam("records") == 0) {
        setStatus("Your search did not return any results");
    }
}
```

This just seems a little hacky..  would like to just have the grid not load any data initially.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should just use `datatype: 'local'` initially. At the moment when you need to load the data you should change the `datatype` to `json` or `xml`:

```
$("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Comment: Tried that - issue is with `datatype:local` and no `url`, my `loadComplete` callback is still called.  I was hoping for an approach that would not trigger the callback - or at least a cleaner way in the callback to determine this is the initial time the grid is loaded.

Comment: @Marcus: of cause the `loadComplete` event handle will be called in all situations. If you want to show a message only in case of loading from the server you can display the message only if `datatype` is equal to "json" like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564898/jqgrid-programatically-select-grid-row/3571392#3571392

Answer (score 25):

I wanted to create a grid that loads no data when the page is loaded but loads data, when the user clicks refresh or uses the search. My solution is a little bit hacky to but is very easy and works nicely.

I am using the callback event `loadBeforeSend` to stop the ajax request for data when the page is loaded. My callback function removes itself so it will be executed only once.

```
loadBeforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
  this.p.loadBeforeSend = null; //remove event handler
  return false; // dont send load data request
}
```

Comment: Why this is´nt the answer I have used this on all my grids(the ones that don´t need to load)

Comment: I use the following to prevent the initial load then trigger the toolbar search which has default values loaded for the initial grid search I want loaded.

`loadBeforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            this.p.loadBeforeSend = null; //remove event handler
            setTimeout(function() {
              $jqGrid[0].triggerToolbar();
            });
            return false; // dont send load data request
          }`

Answer (score -2):

Do not set URL when you initialize the Grid. Set URL just before loading the grid using setGridParam function.

It works for me.