# free-jqGrid External Filtering Used With Grid's beforeRequest() or onPaging() Event

Tags: forms, jqgrid, external, custom-events

Using jqGrid free (version 4.15.6) to show very basic information about invoices (ie: date created, date due, client, total, status).  The invoices grid only has a few pertinent columns that are displayed because it is just not needed to show more than that. In reality there are a lot of other invoice-related fields that are not shown.  I would like to offer end-users the ability to filter the grid based on a lot of these other parameters that are simply not part of the grid contents.

I know jqGrid offers built-in searching, and you can easily just add hidden columns with all the data, but I feel this is not good for us--invoices contain a lot of data--data that is not necessarily present in just the invoices database table.  We want the grid to provide many other filtering options outside of the base invoice data but we do NOT want to use the built-in filter options.  Instead, I would like to use a separate HTML table with a bunch of search fields that our server-side code would know how to pull back).  When one decides to invoke the external filter, we want the grid to load all invoices matching that combined filter.  And if one chooses to navigate using the grid's paging buttons, we want the grid to continue using the original external filtering parameters.

Hope this makes sense.  Maybe I am just overthinking this but I am fairly certain the grid is designed to use it's built in filtering/searching tools/dialog and I have not found anyway to override this behavior. Actually I have using an older jqGrid but that involved using jQuery to completely REPLACE the default pager with custom HTML and event handling.  I never could figure this out with older jqGrid so I chose to write it myself.  But that code is less than optimum and even I know it is subject to much criticism.  Having upgraded to 4.15.6, I want to do this the best way and I want to keep it logical and practical.

I have tried using beforeRequest() and onPaging() events to change the 'url' parameter, thinking that if I modified the url, I could change the GET to include all of our custom filtering fields.  It seems that does not work as the url NEVER changes from the originally defined value.  Console logging does show the events firing but no change to url.  On top of that, the grid ALWAYS passes its own page field, _search field, etc. to the server so the server NEVER sees the filter request.

How does one define their own custom filtering coupled with paging loader and still take advantage of the built-in paging events?  What am I missing?

**** DELETED CODE THAT WAS ADDED TO QUESTION THAT DID NOT PERTAIN TO ORIGINAL QUESTION ISSUE *********

Comment: In Guriddo jqGrid there is a not documented parameter **columns** in searchGrid method. This parameter when defined overwrite the colModel allowing to define your own search dialog table and keep in sync the paging and other actions. I could not tell you if it is available in free-jqGrid too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer on your question because you didn't posted code fragments, which shows how you use jqGrid and because the total number of data, which could be needed to display in all pages isn't known.

In general there are two main alternatives implementing of custom filtering:

- server side filtering
- client side filtering

One can additionally use a mix from both filtering. For example, one can load from the server all invoices based on some fixed filters (all invoices of specific user or all invoices of one organization, all invoices of the last month) and then use `loadonce: true, forceClientSorting: true` options to sort and to filter the returned data on the client side. The user could additionally to filter the subset of data locally using filter toolbar of searching dialog.

The performance of client side is essentially improved last years and loading relatively large JSON data from the server could be done very quickly. Because of that Client-Side-Filtering is strictly recommended. For better understanding the performance of local sorting, filtering and paging I'd recommend you to try the functionality on [the demo](https://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-5000-25-free-jqgrid.htm). You will see that the timing of local filtering of the grid with 5000 rows and 13 columns is better as you can expect mostly from the round trip to the server and processing of server side filtering on some very good organized database. It's the reason why I recommend to consider to use client side sorting (or `loadonce: true, forceClientSorting: true` options) as far it's possible.

If you need to filter data *on the server* then you need just send additional parameters to the server on every request. One can do that by including additional parameters in `postData`. See [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) for additional details. Alternatively one can use `serializeGridData` to extend/modify the data, which will be set to the server.

After the data are loaded from the server, it could be sorted and filtered locally *before* the first page of data will be displayed in the grid. To force local filtering one need just add `forceClientSorting: true` additionally to well known `loadonce: true` parameter. It force applying *local* logic on the data returned from the server. Thus one can use `postData.filters`, `search: true` to force additional local filtering and  `sortname` and `sortorder` parameter to force local sorting.

One more important remark about using hidden columns. Every hidden column will force creating DOM elements, which represent unneeded `<td>` elements. The more DOM elements you place on the page the more slow will be the page. If local data will be used (or if `loadonce: true` be used) then jqGrid hold data associated with every row twice: once as JavaScript object and once as cells in the grid (`<td>` elements). Free jqGrid allows to use "additional properties" instead of hidden columns. In the case no data will be placed in DOM of the grid, but the data will be hold in JavaScript objects and **one able to sort or filter by additional properties in the same way like with other columns**. In the simplest way one can remove all hidden columns and to add `additionalProperties` parameter, which should be array of strings with the name of additional properties. Instead of strings elements of `additionalProperties` could be objects of the same structures like `colModel`. For example, `additionalProperties: [{ name: "taskId", sorttype: "integer"}, "isFinal"]`. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/filterByAdditionalProperties.htm) as an example. The input data of the grid can be seen [here](https://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/sortfunc.json). [Another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/filterByAdditionalPropertiesAndSearchingDialog1.htm) shows that searching dialog contains additional properties additionally to jqGrid column. The commented part `columns` of `searching` shows more advanced way to specify the list and the order of columns and additional properties displayed in searching dialog.

Comment: I have been able to combine several of your other demos from comments posted to similar questions.  I have v4.15.6 working nicely with a custom external filtering form, and keeping built-in paging in tact.  But, because invoices can contain so much data, it is best to let the server provide the core that makes up the primary grid contents, then use client-side to quickly filter the visible columns as you suggest.  However, I want to control grid load based on one of two things:  1) status or client being passed to PHP script as url parameters on first page load, or....

Comment: 2) all external filterable options being passed via the postData and grid reload on standard paging.  So, if the grid is being loaded because of normal paging, then apply the existing postData filters (if any).  But if the grid is being loaded on initial page load, I want to have the grid load only invoices in 'UnPaid' status and possibly assigned to specific client, and when paging, the grid should keep those two parameters as filters.  Can you provide a sample that shows one how to set up filtering of the jqGrid on initial page load?

Comment: @Chance: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean. In general, if you want to use pure server side filtering then you have to implement all required logic yourself. For example, you can use some `postData` for initial loading and then modify it. You can use `var p = $("#gridid").jqGrid("getGridParam")` to get *all* parameters of jqGrid you can change/replace `p.postData` at any time later of just add or remove some properties/methods of `p.postData` object. Additionally you can use `localStorage` to save/restore some initial filters for the next visit of the same page.

Comment: @Chance: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663268/315935) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935) examples of usage `localStorage` together with jqGrid.

Comment: I have filtering defined on server and it works perfectly.  I understand what you mean about changing the postData, following initial load.  But what I still cannot do is get the grid to present data to the server in such a way that I know the grid is making that first call to server.   I have tried everything from adding params to physical address bar in browser, passing default params in url or postData in jqGrid options to define default options.  I cannot force the grid to filter on first page load.  I am not looking to use localStorage--I just want to define default filtering.....

Comment: so that when the grid invokes the script defined by the url param, the grid also passes the two default filtering params and sets _search to true so that the server-side code knows to filter and returns the json data..

Comment: Very frustrating because on page load where no filter is set, the filter form has the proper filter values set for status/client, but the grid loads all invoices. At this point, the grid has already asked server for records.  As soon as I post the filter AFTER the initial page load, the grid has the desired records......

Comment: I thought about setting a timeout function and loading the default filter that way, but that is TWO grid loads.  The jqGrid invokes the url twice in this case--first on page load, then on timeout to set default filter. I would like just that first invocation to server to contain the default filtering presented by the grid. I tried data: '{$json_encoded_initial_data}' but that did nothing.  The grid still  reached out to url param for the records completely ignoring the data.

Comment: Oleg, I have edited original question and posted some of the code.  At this point I feel the question is no longer on topic.  And only posting some codes seems even more confusing.  There is just no way to post everything.  I hope you can see from the code what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Chance: I see that your server side code filter if `_search=true` and `filters` is set. You write multiple times, that you want to use *initial filter*, but your code don't set any initial filter. To set initial filter you need just add `search: true` parameter of jqGrid (it will be sent to the server as `_search=true`) and to set `postData.filters` parameter.

Comment: @Chance: I included links to some demos in my answer. You can examine the code of [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/filterByAdditionalProperties.htm) for example and to use Developer Tools (Network tab) to see that `_search: true` and `filters: {"groupOp":"AND","groups":[],"rules":[{"field":"isFinal","op":"eq","data":"1"}]}` be sent to the server *during initial* request to the server to load the data. Is it not what you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178716/discussion-between-chance-and-oleg).

Comment: Oleg, As mentioned in several comments, can you show me an example where the default filter is set on initial page load?  I need a solution that allows me to request a default filter on initial page load that also allows grid pagination keeping default filter in place until such time a new filter is set by end-user.  I do not want  to persist across different sessions so local storage is too much.  Just want the grid initially loaded with unpaid invoices.  Seems this should be simple but I am failing.  Can you provide a very generic sample that focuses on nothing else but default load filter?

Comment: @Chance: I repeat: you need to do 2 things: 1) add the option `postData.filters` with **initial filter**, which you want to apply 2) add `search: true` to enable the filter. Did you tried that?

Comment: Oleg, sorry for not being clearer.  How can we communicate where I am not limited to text length?  I have tried posting many things and this forum keeps saying I am over the character limit.  I like to think I am fairly intelligent and have tried all sorts of things you recommend.  I have tried setting initial postData.filters in grid def.  That resulted in infinite AJAX calls to server--grid never finished loading.  As of this moment, no invoices should load at first (php IF clause on testing $_search param stil evals to true on INITIAL page load even with not being set!).

Comment: @Chance: Which `mtype` you use: "GET" or "POST"? If the list of parameters could be long then you have to use HTTP method "POST" instead of "GET". It has no restrictions in the length of parameters

Comment: Oleg, the length I am talking about is comment-length in this forum.  I am not talking about length of request.  Can you create a very basic example grid def that defines an initial filter?  I have tried all that I can using all of your demos and nothing is providing the perfect all around solution. I have custom filtering with default pagination working great. But I just cannot set the default filter USING GRID CONSTRUCT.  You say I have not but I assure you I have tried defining initial postData.filters--does not work for me.  BTW, using GET (the default) and only sending two tiny param vals

Comment: @Chance: I can only guess about the reason of your problem, because you describe it instead of posting code fragments. I wrote you before that [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/filterByAdditionalProperties.htm) is an example of initial loading. You can use Developer Tools of Chrome/IE (Network tab) to see that initial Ajax request to URL `http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/sortfunc.json?filters={"groupOp":"AND","groups":[],"rules":[{"field":"isFinal","op":"eq","data":"1"}]}&_search=true&nd=1535213227354&rows=10000&page=1&sidx=taskId&sord=asc` (in encodded form).

Comment: @Chance: Thus if the server would be implement server side filtering then no client side filtering used in the demo will not required. As far I know your server code test for `_search=true` and `filters` parameters. Thus it should return filtered orders already for initial loading. You need just to set `filters` to the value of initial filter.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive my answering like this but this question started out on one subject related to filtering and paging but with using an external filtering source.  Oleg actually has several demos over many threads that I was able to use to accomplish the custom filtering and maintain default built-in paging.  So his answer will be the accepted answer for the original question topic.

But in the solution of original, I encountered another issue with loading the grid initially. I wanted to have the grid load with default filtering values should no other filter already be in place. That really should have been a different question because it really did not affect the first.

I found yet another Oleg reply on a completely different question:

[jqGrid - how to set grid to NOT load any data initially?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934629/jqgrid-how-to-set-grid-to-not-load-any-data-initially).

Oleg answered that question and that answer solved our second need to load one way, then allow another way.

So, on initial load, we look for the filter params server-side.  None given? We pull records using default filtering. Params present? We use initial provided params. The difference with initial loading we do not AJAX exit.  We instead json_encode the data and place it in the grid definition as follows:

```
$('#grd_invoices').jqGrid(
...
url: '{$modulelink}&sm=130',
data: {$json_encoded_griddata},
datatype: 'local',
...
});
```

Since the datatype is set to 'local', the grid does NOT go to server initially, so the data parameter is used by the grid.  Once we are ready to filter, we use Oleg's solution from yet another answer on yet another question to dynamically apply the filter as follows:

```
var myfilter = { groupOp: 'AND', rules: []};
myfilter.rules.push({field:'fuserid',op:'eq',data:$('#fuserid').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'finvoicenum',op:'eq',data:$('#finvoicenum').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'fdatefield',op:'eq',data:$('#fdatefield').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'fsdate',op:'eq',data:$('#fsdate').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'fedate',op:'eq',data:$('#fedate').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'fwithin',op:'eq',data:$('#fwithin').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'fnotes',op:'eq',data:$('#fnotes').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'fdescription',op:'eq',data:$('#fdescription').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'fpaymentmethod',op:'eq',data:$('#fpaymentmethod').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'fstatus',op:'eq',data:$('#fstatus').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'ftotalfrom',op:'eq',data:$('#ftotalfrom').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'ftotal',op:'eq',data:$('#ftotal').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'fmake',op:'eq',data:$('#fmake').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'fmodel',op:'eq',data:$('#fmodel').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'fserial',op:'eq',data:$('#fserial').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'fitemid',op:'eq',data:$('#fitemid').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'ftaxid',op:'eq',data:$('#ftaxid').val()});
myfilter.rules.push({field:'fsalesrepid',op:'eq',data:$('#fsalesrepid').val()});

var grid = $('#grd_invoices');
grid[0].p.search = myfilter.rules.length>0;
$.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:JSON.stringify(myfilter)});
$('#grd_invoices').jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid',[{page:1}]);
```

This allows us to have the grid show initial data loaded locally, and then subsequent filtering changes the grid datatype to 'json', which forces the grid to go to server with new filter params where it loads the more specific filtering.

Credit goes to Oleg because I used many of his posts from many questions to reach the end result.  Thank you @Oleg!