# JQGrid Programatically Select and View Grid Row after loading

Tags: jqgrid, navigation, client-side

I have a JQGrid with loadonce:true(so it's all client side) and paging enabled.

**After loading the grid**, I would like to specify a row(programatically, without user input) and have my grid navigate to the corresponding page to select the specified row.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564898/jqgrid-programatically-select-grid-row/3571392#3571392). If you produce on the server side the results sorted correspond to the requested sort order you can calculate the page number where the selected row is. Then the server should send back **all data** instead of only one page requested, but insert in the `userData` the page number where the selected row will be and the rowid which should be selected. The client part which use such data from the server con be [following](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DataToSelect.htm).

Comment: I saw the old answer and the link on the client part.
The purpose is to be able to add a record programatically after loading the grid and to refresh the grid and to select the row of the inserted record.