# jqGrid and preselection of rows with multiselect option

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, multi-select

I have a jqGrid with multiselect.
I would like to be able to pre-check a certain number of rows if another column is true, for example.
What I've done so far is passing an element (column) from the server which contains a boolean. 
I hide this column in the gridComplete event.
I can I select - and check a predefined row during the load of the grid?

UPDATE:

This is my code:

```
jQuery("#OrdersGrid").jqGrid({
    url: $.SalesOrders.url.OrdersFetchUrl,
    postData: { OrderStatus: orderStatus },
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['N.Ordine', 'Cliente', 'Ragione Sociale', 'Stato', 'Fido', 'Data', ''],
    colModel: [
               { name: 'Number', index: 'Number', editable: false, resizable: true, sortable: false, width: 76, align: 'left' },
               { name: 'CustomerCode', index: 'CustomerCode', editable: false, resizable: true, sortable: false, width: 50, align: 'left' },
               { name: 'CustomerName', index: 'CustomerName', editable: false, resizable: true, sortable: false, width: 410, align: 'left' },
               { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', editable: false, resizable: true, sortable: false, width: 40, align: 'center' },
               { name: 'LoCStatus', index: 'LoCStatus', editable: false, resizable: true, sortable: false, width: 40, align: 'center' },
               { name: 'Date', index: 'Date', editable: false, resizable: true, sortable: false, width: 70, align: 'right' },
               { name: 'Checked', index: 'Checked', editable: false, resizable: false, visible: false }
              ],
    pager: $('#OrdersPager'),
    rowNum: 30,
    width: 794,
    height: 220,
    viewrecords: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    scroll: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    hidegrid: false,
    multiselect: true,
    emptyrecords: "Nessun record presente",
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        if (data.rows.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
                if (data.rows[i].cell[6] == 'true') {
                    jQuery("#OrdersGrid").jqGrid('setSelection', data.rows[i].id, true);
                }
            }
        }
        jQuery("#OrdersGrid").jqGrid('hideCol', 'Checked');
    }
});
```

I've implemented Oleg's solution and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't posted the definition of the grid which you use, so some questions for me stay opened. Nevertheless I hope that you will find the answer on your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564898/jqgrid-programatically-select-grid-row/3571392#3571392). In [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DataToMultiSelect.htm) included in the answer are used the parameter `loadonce:true` which makes all more complex. The rows which will be selected are not on the first page of the loaded data. Moreover, in the demo there are no columns (even hidden) which can be used to determine which rows should be selected. Instead of that the information about the selection in the grid will be sent from the server as a part of `userdata` part of the JSON response. This way is more general and I hope it will work also in your grid.

**UPDATED**: I find your code good. I seen only small places for optimization:

1. The properties `editable: false`, `resizable: true` and `align: 'left'` are default in the `colModel` (see [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options)). So I suggest you to remove the values.
2. The property `visible: false` don't exist in the `colModel`. You mean probably `hidden: true`. After the usage of correct property the statement `jQuery("#OrdersGrid").jqGrid('hideCol', 'Checked');` will be not needed in the `loadComplete`.
3. Instead of the usage `jQuery("#OrdersGrid")` every time in the loop you can save the value in a variable: `var mygrid = jQuery("#OrdersGrid");` before jqGrid initialization and then your code will be `mygrid.jqGrid({...,loadComplete: function (data) {...mygrid.jqGrid('setSelection', ...`

Some additional remarks. The statement `data.rows[i].cell[6] = 'true'` shows that you serialize `Checked` property with `Checked.ToString()`. You can use `Checked?"1":"0"` instead and reduce the size of the data transfered. I use many grids with the `formatter:"checkbox"` which interpret both "1" and "true" like checked. In your case you are absolutely free in the format of data, so you can use "1" and "0" or even "1" and "".

If you use Checked column only to transfer the information about row selection you can remove `Checked` column from the grid at all. In the `data` parameter of `loadComplete` you will still see the `Checked` property (the `data.rows[i].cell[6]`), but you reduce the number of columns.

Comment: I've attached some code. As you can see my MVC controller streams a column Checked which is my discriminator.I've used the example in one of the links you've sent me and it works fine. What do you think about this solution?

Comment: @LeftyX: I updated my answer with some small suggestion to your code.

Comment: very helpful.I tend not to optimize javascript but I know I should, as I do with the server side.