# is there anyway to pass back additional data in jqgrid treeGrid url request?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid, treegrid

i am [using jqgrid treeview](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atreegrid) and i am passing back json response which works great.  There is some additional information about the request that i would like to pass back to the GUI and i wanted to see the best way of doing this.

the only way i can think of now is to have another column in the treegrid and shove this data into the json response.

Is there any other way to pass back additional data to display on the client side outside the exact response to populate the tree ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like in case of standard grid you can fill the `userdata` part of the JSON data (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848815/how-to-read-userdata-in-jqgrid/3849513#3849513) for more information). The value of the `userdata` can be any object in any format. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564898/jqgrid-programatically-select-grid-row/3571392#3571392) I used the data to send information about the row(s) which should be selected after the grid are filled.

Additionally you can extend the standard JSON data with **any additional information**. The information will be ignored by jqGrid, but you have access to **the whole data** sent from the server inside of the [loadComplete(data)](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handler.

Comment: but in the treegrid response i am simply sending back an array of rows in the json.  no other data (like rows:, total:, etc) . . where would i stick this additional data ??

Comment: @ooo: tree grid use the same `jsonReader` as "standard" grid. You need just fill additional hidden rows. So you can use `userdata` like before.