# How to read extra data in jqgrid coming from Web service response to jQgrid

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am new in jQgrid. My webservice giving additional data of columns datatype in JSON response to jQgrid other than page, total, records and rows. My JSON string is as follows :

```
{"d":
{"__type":"iReg.JQGrid","page":1,"total":20,"records":194,
"rows":[{"id":"560013cb-9c86-4471-8379-031cea98c507","cell":["TENDERSTATUS","Won - PO Received",""]},
{"id":"88170912-1b2a-441f-9002-0be93e0bcd8f","cell":["ORDERTYPE","Development","Development order"]},
{"id":"e67284f7-4f42-456b-b1a9-04cabaf77305","cell":["ORDERSTATUS","Pending","Pending - Default status"]},
{"id":"14ba5274-e60d-441a-887b-0a999f5a4e4c","cell":["ITEMPROCESS_STEP","Blend","Blending Process"]},
{"id":"aa7857a7-de94-42bf-8075-0ab3d3d65bf1","cell":["EXPENSE_SUBTYPE","Stationary","Stationary"]},
{"id":"b0ab6cd8-4e21-4350-8970-03cd4aaa6d61","cell":["EXPENSE_SUBTYPE","Food","Food"]},
{"id":"57a36caa-01f8-489f-b469-0a803d25c1c6","cell":["DOCUMENT_CATEGORY","Acceptance Note","Acceptance Note"]},
{"id":"9d39f81e-a524-49e8-a0b5-09a865533913","cell":["DESIGNATION","Sales Engineer","Sales Engineer"]},
{"id":"880a2441-e0db-4cda-978c-01387c969df6","cell":["CITY","Noida","U.P."]},
{"id":"0000a8c4-82b8-4ad6-a122-00938307e269","cell":["AIPRIORITY","Medium","Medium priority for action item"]}],
"coldatatypes":["String","String","String"]
}}
```

In above JSON string, **coldatatypes** is the additional data which I want to read this in jqgrid and want to sore in one variable so that i can use it for my other purpose. Is it possible??

**.cs file** : Property to read and store value

```
   public class JQGrid
   {
      ........
      ........ 
      public List<string> coldatatype { get; set; }
       public JQGrid()
       {
           .......
           coldatatype = new List<string>();
       }
    }
```

Comment: @Oleg here explains how its done properly read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669540/is-there-anyway-to-pass-back-additional-data-in-jqgrid-treegrid-url-request

Comment: @CodeDestroyer : Your suggestion has work. I am getting extra data in loadComplete. Whatever data I am getting is the datatypes of all columns of table in array format. Keelp supporting like this. Thanx a lot..