# JQGrid: Binding JSON data to MultiSelect Checkbox

Tags: wcf, json, jqgrid

I have JQGrid loading data from WCF OperationContract with paging and sorting working fine.  I am using "multiselect: true" so that I get the checkbox column and ability to select multiple rows.  I've implemented gridComplete:, onSelectAll: and onSelectRow: to capture when checkboxes are checked/unchecked and to maintain checked state upon pagination.  I am able to save the checkbox state to the DB via another WCF method call.

What I cannot figure out how to do is load the saved checkbox state for each row along with the other fields specified in colModel:.

Any ideas?  I realize I can make a separate WCF service call to get the values, loop through them and set state manually, but that seems like a huge waste and overly clunky.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, which I imagine me immediately after reading of your question, is to have **additional hidden column** (`hidden: true` property in the `colModel` for the column) and the checkboxes inside. You can load the selection state from the database an fill the hidden checkboxes. Inside of `loadComplete` or `gridComplete` you can use the information to select the rows.

If you would use `loadComplete` instead of `gridComplete` you can even eliminate the need to hold hidden row. The callback method `loadComplete` has `data` parameter which are initialized with the data originated from the `ajax` call. So if your server response contain more information as jqGrid need the data will be ignored by jqGrid, but you can see the data in the `loadComplete` and use the information to set row selection.

Comment: Oleg!  I think I will try loadComplete and manually set with the data param, so I don't have to create an additional, hidden column, since I already have it working with multiselect: true. It would be nice however, if the the checkbox field added by multiselect could automatically be bound like the rest of the fields.  Thanks!

Comment: @RadiusMaximus: Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575192/jqgrid-change-background-color-of-row-based-on-row-cell-value-by-column-name/6575634#6575634) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080859/jqgrid-iterate-over-the-grid-data-in-a-subgrid/7084920#7084920) which show how to enumerate the rows and do some action in every row. [Another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564898/jqgrid-programatically-select-grid-row/3571392#3571392) do close work as you need. The usage of [jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) can be also helpful.

Comment: I can't use loadComplete.  it's not being called because I do this:

datatype: function (pdata) {
  beginGridRequest('Retailers');
  getRetailerData(pdata)
},

Comment: I posed new question about loadComplete not firing:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451198/jqgrid-loadcomplete-not-firing-when-datatype-function