# JQGrid: loadComplete NOT firing when datatype: function

Tags: jqgrid

If I call a function to load my grid data, loadComplete does not fire.  I need to handle this event so I can manually update multiselect checkbox correctly.  If I update in gridComplete, I have to click the checkbox twice to uncheck it.

Comment: In 99% of cases the usage of `datatype` as function is not needed. Could you include the source code which you use?

Answer (score 5):

In your previous question you wrote that you use WCF on the server side. In the case **you don't need to use `datatype` as function**. Instead of that you can just use the following parameters:

```js
datatype: "json",
ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
serializeGridData: function (data) {
    return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

To be sure that `JSON.stringify` are supported in old web browsers you should include `json2.js` which you can load from [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

In [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912008/jqgrid-does-not-populate-with-data/3914796#3914796) you can find more code examples (and download the demo) which shows how you can use WCF with jqGrid.

Now I will answer on your original question: "Why `loadComplete` does not fire" if you use `datatype` as function. The short answer is: if you use `datatype` as function **your code** is responsible for calling of `loadComplete`.

If you use `datatype` as function *your code* is responsible to some things which jqGrid do typically. So first of all *you have to understand what should the `datatype` function do*. An example from the documentation (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#function)) shows the simplest, but not full, implementation of `datatype` as function. More full code example looks like the following:

```js
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: "example.php",
    mtype: "GET",
    datatype: function (postdata, loadDivSelector) {
        var ts = this,  // cache 'this' to use later in the complete callback
            p = this.p; // cache the grid parameters
        $.ajax({
           url: p.url,
           type: p.mtype,
           dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/json",
           data: JSON.stringify(postdata),
           cache: p.mtype.toUpperCase() !== "GET",
           beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
               // show the loading div
               $($.jgrid.jqID(loadDivSelector)).show();
               // if loadBeforeSend defined in the jqGrid call it
               if ($.isFunction(p.loadBeforeSend)) {
                   p.loadBeforeSend.call(ts, jqXHR);
               }
           },
           complete: function () {
               // hide the loading div
               $($.jgrid.jqID(loadDivSelector)).hide();
           },
           success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
               ts.addJSONData(data);
               // call loadComplete
               if ($.isFunction(p.loadComplete)) {
                   p.loadComplete.call(ts, data);
               }
               // change datatype to "local" to support
               // "loadonce: true" or "treeGrid: true" parameters
               if (p.loadonce || p.treeGrid) {
                   p.datatype = "local";
               }
           },
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               if ($.isFunction(p.loadError)) {
                   p.loadError.call(ts, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
           }
        });
    },
    ... // other parameters
});
```

You can see that the code in not so short. In the above example we still not support some jqGrid options like virtual scrolling (`scroll: 1` or `scroll: true`).

Nevertheless I hope that I cleared now *why* I don't recommend to use `datatype` as function. If you use it you have to understand many things *how jqGrid work internally*. You should examine it's source code to be sure that you do all things correctly. If you skip somethings, than your code will works incorrect in some situations or in some combination of jqGrid parameters.

If you look at the code which I included at the beginning of my answer (the usage of `ajaxGridOptions` and `serializeGridData`) you will see that the code is very easy. Moreover **it works with all other legal combination of jqGrid parameters**. For example you can use `loadonce: true`, `loadComplete`, `loadError` or even virtual scrolling (`scroll: 1` or `scroll: true`). All things needed depend on the parameters **do jqGrid for you**.