# My jQgrid is not displaying json data

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I am new in jQgrid and jQuery. I want to display JSON data in my jQgrid. But my code is not showing the jSON data which is coming from server and also I am mot getting any error for this. Where my code is going wrong??

From server side, JSON string is coming in the format of(From preview window)

```
d: {__type:iReg.JQGrid, page:1, total:20, records:194, rows:[,…]}
 __type: "iReg.JQGrid"
 page: 1
 records: 194
 rows: [,…]
 0: {id:0000a8c4-82b8-4ad6-a122-00938307e269, cell:[AIPRIORITY, Medium, Medium priority for action item]}
 1: {id:880a2441-e0db-4cda-978c-01387c969df6, cell:[CITY, Noida, U.P.]}
 2: {id:9d39f81e-a524-49e8-a0b5-09a865533913, cell:[DESIGNATION, Sales Engineer, Sales         Engineer]}
 3: {id:57a36caa-01f8-489f-b469-0a803d25c1c6, cell:[DOCUMENT_CATEGORY, Acceptance Note, Acceptance Note]}
 4: {id:aa7857a7-de94-42bf-8075-0ab3d3d65bf1, cell:[EXPENSE_SUBTYPE, Stationary, Stationary]}
 5: {id:b0ab6cd8-4e21-4350-8970-03cd4aaa6d61, cell:[EXPENSE_SUBTYPE, Food, Food]}
 6: {id:14ba5274-e60d-441a-887b-0a999f5a4e4c, cell:[ITEMPROCESS_STEP, Blend, Blending Process]}
 7: {id:e67284f7-4f42-456b-b1a9-04cabaf77305, cell:[ORDERSTATUS, Pending, Pending - Default status]}
 8: {id:88170912-1b2a-441f-9002-0be93e0bcd8f, cell:[ORDERTYPE, Development, Development order]}
 9: {id:560013cb-9c86-4471-8379-031cea98c507, cell:[TENDERSTATUS, Won - PO Received, Won - PO Received]}
 total: 20
```

And my jQgrid intilization code is :

```
var oItemGrid = $("#ItemGrid");
        oItemGrid.jqGrid({
            url: 'WSAjax.asmx/GetDataForGrid',
            mtype: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            ajaxGridOptions:
            {
                contentType: "application/json"
            },
            serializeGridData: function (data) {
                return JSON.stringify(data);
            },
            colNames: ['Type', 'Name', 'Desc'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Type', index: 'Type', width: 40 },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 40 },
                { name: 'Desc', index: 'Desc', width: 40, sortable: false}],
            prmNames: { page: "pageIndex", rows: "pageSize", sort: "sortIndex", order: "sortDirection", search: "_search" },
            autowidth: true,
            height: 'auto',
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
            jsonReader:
            {
                root:"type",
                page:"page",
                total:"total",
                records:"records",
                repeatitems: false,
                cell:"cell",
                id:"id"
            },
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            caption: 'Remember Sorting and Filtering Functionality',
            pager: '#IGPager',
            onSortCol: function (colModel, colName, sortOrder) {
                saveSortInfoToCookie("ItemGridSortInfo", $("#ItemGrid"));
                var storeval = $.cookie("ItemGridSortInfo");
                alert("Saving sort info in cookie: " + storeval);
            },
            //loadonce: true
        }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#IGPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false }, {}, {}, {}, {}, {});
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you forget closing `}` at the end of JSON data which you posted. After the small fix you need to fix the main problem: you need modify `jsonReader` so that it corresponds the JSON data which you posted. You can use for example

```
jsonReader: {
    root: "d.rows",
    page: "d.page",
    total: "d.total",
    records: "d.records"
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Rahul.htm) demonstrate the results.

By the way if you works with grids having about 200 rows totally you can consider to use `loadonce: true` option. In the case the server should return *all data* from the server independent from `pageIndex` and `pageSize`. You need still sort the data corresponds to `sortIndex` and `sortDirection`. You will don't need to implement server side sorting (filtering) of the data. The advantage will be: 1) simplifying the server code 2) simplifying interface between the server and the client 3) better responsible frontend (from the users point of view) because paging, sorting and filtering of the data will be implemented on the client side and the user will see the results practically immediately.

Comment: Your are great Oleg.... :D... your suggestion has work. but why you not used repeatitems:"false" or "true". I read about repeatItems in documentation [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data). But I didn't understood that. Please can u explain me according my scenario....

Comment: @Rahul: Items of data `{"id":"0000a8c4-82b8-4ad6-a122-00938307e269", "cell":["AIPRIORITY", "Medium", "Medium priority for action item"]}` corresponds default `repeatitems: true` so you can skip the setting. The property `repeatitems: true` means that you need use items like `{"id": "0000a8c4-82b8-4ad6-a122-00938307e269", "Type": "AIPRIORITY", "Name": "Medium", "Desc": "Medium priority for action item"}`

Comment: Ok I understood.. Thanx a lot. So on what scenario we can use `repeatItems:false`. Please tell me this one.... So that both the scenario will be cleared for me...