# jqgrid default pagination not working with ajax and xml data

Tags: ajax, xml, servlets, jqgrid

I have created a jqgrid as follows:

```
$("#table_jqgrid").jqGrid({
            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            datatype: function(postdata) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'getxmlInfo',
                    data:postdata,
                    dataType:"xml",
                    complete: function(xmldata,stat){
                        debugger;
                        console.log(xmldata);
                        if(stat=="success") {
                            var thegrid = jQuery("#table_jqgrid")[0];
                            console.log(thegrid)
                            debugger;
                            thegrid.addXmlData(xmldata.responseXML);


                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            colNames: ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6'],
            colModel :[ 
                {name: 'col1', index: 'col1', width: 60, sorttype: "int"},
                {name: 'col2', index: 'col2', width: 90, sorttype: "date"},
                {name: 'col3', index: 'col3', width: 100},
                {name: 'col4', index: 'col14', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float"},
                {name: 'col5', index: 'col5', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float"},
                {name: 'col6', index: 'col6', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float"}
            ],

            pager: '#pager_jqgrid',
            loadonce:true,
            rowNum:10,

            rowList:[10,20,30],
            sortname: 'col1',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            rowTotal:40,             
            viewrecords: true,


        });
```

Everything is working fine when changing records per page.But pagination is not correct.
**getxmlInfo** is a url to servlet function which returns corresponding xml as ajax response.

Initially page number is 1 and records/page is 10 then 10 rows will be shown.Is there any way to set total number of pages in jqgrid?

After a long search one link revealed there exists an option that is setting rowTotal parameter.But it is not working .How we can persist pagination data on each ajax call.Is there exists any solution to set totalrows on each ajax call.

Comment: Why you use `datatype` as function instead of usage `datatype: "xml"`? **How many rows will be returned from the server? (10 or all)?** Do you implemented the server side paging or you want to use *client side paging*? **Which version of jqGrid/free jqGrid/Guriddo jqGrid JS you use?**

Comment: @Oleg  In order to use ajax call ,datatype is used as a function.Otherwise how we can trigger ajax call on jqgrid loading..No need to retrieve all rows from server.For that I have implemented a function that returns only required number of rows according to current page and records/page.I wish to use default pagination provided by jqgrid itself.I am working with  **jqGrid  4.6.0**

Answer (score 0):

I would strictly recommend you don't use `datatype` as function if you need make just an Ajax call to the server. More as 90% of the code which implements such feature uses it in a wrong way. Your code for example can send Ajax request only once in Internet Explorer because well known problem with caching of Ajax requests. You use additionally `complete` callback instead of `"success"`, which is also not full correctly. The `"notmodified"` is an example of successful response too. You should never use `jQuery.ajax` if you are not a real specialist in the subject.

You should understated jqGrid also really good to be able to use `datatype` as function. You can find an example of the implementation in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7455157/315935). You can see that the code is not so short. The answer is written many years ago and it's not supports many features added in jqGrid later. The function `datatype` in jqGrid 4.5.3 and later for example contains 5 parameters. The function `addXmlData` which you try to call contains 5 parameters too. Your current implementation of `datatype` break some standard callbacks,  for example `loadComplete`, `loadError`, `beforeProcessing`. Some features of jqGrid like virtual scrolling or frozen columns will be broken too.

I recommend you to replace `datatype` to

```js
url: "getxmlInfo",
datatype: "xml"
```

I recommend you additionally remove all `index` properties from `colModel`. You use `loadonce: true` option which require to the `index` and `name` value are the same. You use for example `name: 'col4', index: 'col14'` which break the rule.

I strictly recommend you to add `gridview: true` option which will just improve performance of the loading of the grid. You should consider to use `autoencode: true` option if the XML data returned from the server don't contains HTML fragments which need be set in the cells of jqGrid.