# How to set highlight on selected row in JqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using two Jqgrids and when I doubleclick on my "main" grid I show another version of the grid. In the new grid I am displaying, I want the row that was selected in the "main" grid to be selected/highlighted.

```
ondblClickRow: function (id, rowid) { //function to get value of selected row and show new grid
            var ret = $("#grid1").getRowData(id);
            loadEditGrid(ret.ID);

            function loadEditGrid(id) {
                $("#grid1").empty();
                jQuery("#grid2").jqGrid({
                    url: 'test.json',
                    datatype: "json",
                    jsonReader: {
                        root: 'rows',
                        repeatitems: false,
                        page: "page",
                        total: "total",
                        records: "records",
                        userData: id,
                        cell: "",
                        id: "ID"
                    },
                    colNames: ['Item Name', 'Item Id'],
                    colModel: [{ name: 'ITEM_NAME', index: 'ITEM_NAME', width: 160 },
                                { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 80}],
                height: "75%"
                });
            }
        },
```

Comment: Do you use `multiselect: true` in the "main" grid?

Comment: Hi, Oleg. No I dont. But I found a solution.

loadComplete: function hightlightRow(selrow) {
$('#' + id).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
}

Comment: But over to another subject. How can I get the page of the selected row?

Comment: because you use *remote* data source (`datetype: 'json'`) you can find the page which need be selected on the server. You can look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3571392/315935) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [setSelection](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method to select any row. It's only important the you should do this *after* the data in the grid are loaded. So you should place the call of `setSelection` inside of `loadComplete` or inside of `gridComplete` callback.